# when does nodejs use epoll_pwait and when it uses epoll_wait

Tags: node.js, system-calls, epoll

I have noticed that when calling a simple code given below

```bash
strace node -e 'setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hola")},10000)'
```

on arm instance (graviton c7g.2xlarge and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS ) with node v18.12.1 it uses epoll_pwait to wait

```
user@laptop:~$ strace -e epoll_pwait,epoll_wait -c node -e 'setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hola")},10000)' 
hola
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           epoll_pwait
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                    10           total
```

while on AMD c6a.2xlarge with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with node v18.12.1 same command waits using epoll_wait

```
user@laptop:~$ strace -e epoll_pwait,epoll_wait -c node -e 'setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hola")},10000)' 
hola
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000012           1        10           epoll_wait
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000012                    10           total
```

my doubts are

1. why is nodejs on arm using epoll_pwait vs epoll_wait on x86 architecture
2. is there any performance hit between using epoll_pwait
   and epoll_wait
3. can this behaviour be made uniform using some configuration or am i missing something in my analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why is nodejs on arm using epoll_pwait vs epoll_wait on x86 architecture

Linux doesn't have the `epoll_wait` syscall on ARM64. When the `epoll_wait` syscall doesn't exist, [Glibc implements the `epoll_wait` function in terms of `epoll_pwait`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/epoll_wait.c;h=8a1ae4c1177a28f8116cc2239ce4e30804aa7e8c;hb=HEAD#l32) instead. This is in accordance with [this comment in the Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h?h=v6.6#n9):

> As a basic principle, no duplication of functionality
> should be added, e.g. we don't use lseek when llseek
> is present. New architectures should use this file
> and implement the less feature-full calls in user space.

---

> 2. is there any performance hit between using epoll_pwait and epoll_wait

On ARM64, this isn't a meaningful question, since there is no `epoll_wait` there to compare to. On x86_64, `epoll_pwait` does slightly more work than `epoll_wait`, as you can see [in their definitions in the Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/eventpoll.c?h=v6.6#n2325), but I doubt it's significant.

---

> 3. can this behaviour be made uniform using some configuration or am i missing something in my analysis.

If you really wanted, you could modify the source of nodejs to use `epoll_pwait` everywhere and then compile it yourself, but I see no benefit to doing this.

Comment: really helpful thanks Joseph